# How do I calculate the texture direction using UV data in the Lithtech Jupiter engine?

Tags: c++, math, game-development

I am trying to reverse engineer the level files for the video game Tron 2.0, and I need help from someone who is either good at Math and/or familiar with Lithtech.

Long story short, I am having trouble mapping textures correctly, and I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible.

I feel like the best way for me to explain the issue is to just provide you with a real world example.

I have a triangle, ABC, with the following vertices and uv's:

```
A.position = (64.0, 0.0, 0.0)
B.position = (61.2172813, 18.6666679, 0.0)
C.position = (43.2871819, 18.6666679, 43.2871284)


A.uv = (0.5, 0.0)
B.uv = (0.478260010, 0.0)
C.uv = (0.338181108, 0.338180691)
```

Each UV is calculated in the following manner:

```
Vertex.uv.u = P.Dot(Vertex.position) / Texture.width
Vertex.uv.v = Q.Dot(Vertex.position) / Texture.height
```

P and Q are two vectors that describe the texture's direction.  It may help you to think of them as the tangent and bitangent, but they do not have to be orthogonal to the normal.

In this particular instance, P and Q have the following values:

```
P = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Q = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

And the texture dimensions are 128 x 128.

So my question is this:

**How would I solve for P and Q if I did not know their values?**

Here are some things to keep in mind:

- P and Q are not always unidirectional.
- P and Q may or may not be orthogonal to the normal.
- A, B, and C are co-planar and share the same P and Q values.
- A, B, and C do not always have zero components.

Lastly, while I welcome any and all help, I have already tried solving for P and Q using Eric Lengyel's [method](https://www.cs.upc.edu/%7Evirtual/G/1.%20Teoria/06.%20Textures/Tangent%20Space%20Calculation.pdf) and variations thereof.  I have also tried several Barycentric [approaches](https://github.com/jsj2008/lithtech/blob/master/tools/shared/world/UVtoOPQ.cpp) without success.  I would love to be proven wrong, however!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have tagged this with `C++`?  *Some* of the code you have shown *may* be C++ but parts of it are clearly **not** (valid) C++.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I used the C++tag because that's the language I'm writing the program in.  The Lithtech engine and the linked examples are also coded in C/C++.  I'm happy to remove the tag, but I thought including it would increase the odds of my question being answered.  That and I thought using pseudo-code instead of C would improve readability.